# Reducing monomials in polynomial rings over finite field using fermat's little theorem using maple.

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, maple

I am trying to do the following: Given a polynomial ring

`Z/3[x_1,x_2,x_3]`

and, say I have two polynomials

```
f1 := x[1]^2.
f2 := 2*x[1].
```

Their sum should be the following

```
f1+f2 = 2*x[1]^3.
```

However, if you reduce the sum using Fermat's little theorem, it should read

```
f1+f2 = 2*x[1].
```

Now, in Maple, one can use "Domains" to work in a specific polynomial ring. However, even in at polynomial ring over a finite field, Maple does not do this reduction. Does anyone know how to get maple to do these reductions throughout a worksheet?

Comment: It is not true that $x^3 = x$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ where $\mathbb{F}_3$ is the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$

Comment: Maybe not equal, but equivalent -- for all intents and purposes they evaluate to the same value under a polynomial mapping.

Comment: No, $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_3$ Those polynomials are (polynomial) functions $\overline{\mathbb{F}_3} \to \overline{\mathbb{F}_3}$, ie. they are determined by their value for $x= a, a \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_3}$ (the algebraic closure of  $\mathbb{F}_3$). $\mathbb{F}_3[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is the same with polynomials in $3$ variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identity polynomials of  $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ giving the same value for $x \in \{0,1,2\}$ then what you need is to look at the quotient ring $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x(x-1)(x-2))=\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3-x)$.

More generally to identity polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ giving the same value for $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$ then you want to look at the quotient ring  $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/(x^q-x)$

Comment: How about in a multivariate case?

Comment: @MGS  $f(x_1,a_2) = 0 \bmod x_1^3-x_1$ for every $a_2$

Comment: ie. $(x_1^3-x_1,x_2^3-x_2)$

Comment: Yea I figured it out just as you wrote this...thanks alot! :)